# Compile Python Program Linux

Tags: python, compilation, executable

Is there a way where I can compile my python program (.py) to become just a regular program that I don't haft to run threw the terminal to run it???

Example I don't wanna do this to run it threw the terminal.

*./whatever.py*

Example I wanna be able to make the file like a Windows .exe, but for Linux like the one below, for example.

http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/4883/executable.png

Comment: Why? You'd rather go `./whatever` instead?

Comment: It already does act like a windows exe, If you open the folder in your favorite file manager you should be able to launch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a frozen binary from python scripts, use [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the first line of your file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and make your file executable by typing (in a terminal):

```
chmod u+x my_file.py
```